# Default to original textarea val on Esc

Tags: jquery, textarea, keypress, var, revert

I'm trying to make an textarea default to the original value upon hitting esc. I can't seem to pass the origVal from the main code into the keypress if/else.

Am I overthinking this or underthinking it?

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/brkbcr5c/1/

```
$(function() {
    var origVal = $("#textarea").val(); // set original value of textarea    
    $('#textarea').keydown(function(e, origVal) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //submit code
        } else if (code == 27) {
            $(this).blur();
            $(this).val(origVal); // default to original value on Esc
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, the `this` in `var origVal = $(this).val()` points to the `document` element.

Use a specific textarea selector.

```
var origVal = $('#textarea').val()
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brkbcr5c/2/)**

Also, remove `origVal` from `keydown(function(e, origVal)`. The global `origVal` is accessible in `keydown`.

Comment: Thanks! You're fast... I actually immediately caught the 'this' issue and updated my question with an updated fiddle.

Comment: Okay then, just remove the additional param from keydown :)